# How would I disable all input exept 1

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want a pause menu that cancels all input when opened exept the menu button. I know how to cancel the input, I just don't know how to not cancel 1 input.

Here's the cancel input function I am using :

```
    public MenuScript menuS;

    public PlayerInput input;  

    private void Update()
    {
        if (menuS.paused == true)
        {
            input.DeactivateInput();
        } else
        {
            input.ActivateInput();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure if there is a built-in functionalty that you can leverage for this one, just keeping a boolean flag might be the solution for this.

Comment: how would I use it for this application

Comment: you already seem to have a field called `menuS.paused`, so you can do at the beginning of your update method like `if(menuS.paused) return;`

Comment: ```menuS.paused``` is just a bool taken from my menuscript. how would ```if(menuS.paused) return;``` work in my situation